# Repeat table header with unique first page

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I'm trying to make a table header in Word 2010, but I need to have one cell that is unique to the first page in the middle of the header. Is this even possible? If so, how do I go about doing it?

The table I have spans multiple pages. I want the table header to repeat across all the pages the table covers. In the table header, one of the cells needs to be unique to the first page. So it might look something like this:

> *Column 1  |  Column 2 (unique text)  |  Column 3*

I want the columns to repeat on all pages, but I want *(unique text)* to only appear on the first page. I already know that I can repeat the header including the unique text by selecting "Repeat Header Rows" under Layout > Data. I just need to know if I can exclude one of the cells in the header from repeating.

Comment: This would be easier to understand if you could post a link to a screenshot or add a mockup to your question.